# RSpec/Ruby - creating a proc inside a `let` block

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to define a `Proc` to be passed around to various methods, and I wanted to define it in a `let` block

```
let(:proc) { Proc.new { |f| f.write("c1,c2,c3") } }
```

However I keep getting the error

```
ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block
```

Although the Proc clearly has a block. When I execute the Proc by itself in `IRB`, it works, so I suspect it's something to do with how `let` initializes it.

Is there a way to work around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not able to replicate this. Perhaps you have an older version of RSpec?

In any case, don't forget that `proc` is Ruby shorthand for `Proc.new`:

```
proc { "hello" }.call
# "hello"

proc
# ArgumentError
```

You may have simply run into a naming collision. Try changing the `let` argument name to something other than "proc".

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling on this:

```
let(:proc) { ->(f) { f.write("c1,c2,c3") } }
```

should work